# How to read Json file using Linq in c#

Tags: c#, json, linq

I have below Json file ,I need to fetch the role_to_secrets of "rec" then I should take respective secrete value for "prod" environment.
Ex:
rec: roles are "resdns","dnsmoon",resmoon", I need to fetch the corresponding "prod" secrets
"prod/user/res_dns.pub","prod/user/resdns.pub","prod/user/res_moon.pub"

```
{
   "secrets":{
      "resdns":{
         "_type":"ssh_key",
         "_rotatable":false,
         "test":"test/user/res_dns.pub",
         "prod":"prod/user/res_dns.pub"
      },
      "dnsmoon":{
         "_type":"secret",
         "_rotatable":false,
         "test":"test/user/dnsmoon.pub",
         "prod":"prod/user/resdns.pub"
      },
      "resmoon":{
         "_type":"secret",
         "_rotatable":false,
         "test":"test/user/res_moon.pub",
         "prod":"prod/user/res_moon.pub"
      },
      "rrservice":{
         "_type":"secret",
         "_rotatable":false,
         "test":"test/user/rrs1ervice.pub",
         "prod":"prod/user/rrservice8.pub"
      },
      "mds":{
         "_type":"ssh_key",
         "_rotatable":false,
         "test":"test/user/mds.pub",
         "prod":"prod/user/mds.pub"
      }
   },
   "role_to_secrets":{
      "rec":[
         "resdns",
         "dnsmoon",
         "resmoon"
      ],
      "kka":[
         "resdns",
         "dnsmoon",
         "resmoon"
      ],
      "zoper":[
         "rrservice",
         "mds"
      ]
   }
}
```

I have used tradition way to fetch the data, But is there any simple way by linq

```
List<string> lstRecursiveRoles = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<string>>(jsonContent["role_to_secrets"]["recursive"].ToString());
List<string> lstSecretValue = new List<string>();
   foreach (var recursiveRole in lstRecursiveRoles)
    {
         lstSecretValue.Add(jsonContent["secrets"][recursiveRole]["prod"].ToString());
    }
```

Comment: There is a [LINQ to JSON](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/LINQtoJSON.htm) provider.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code

```
    var jObj = JObject.Parse(json); 

    string[] roles = ((JObject)jObj["role_to_secrets"]).Properties()
                             .Where(x => x.Name == "rec")
                             .Select(s => s.Value.ToObject<string[]>())
                             .FirstOrDefault();

    List<string> secrets = ((JObject)jObj["secrets"]).Properties()
                    .Where(s => roles.Contains(s.Name))
                    .Select(s => (string)s.Value["prod"])
                    .ToList();
```